# percentage changing in regression coefficient

Tags: regression, logistic-regression

suppose we have following regression model
[image]

basic question is : if we  change  (increase or decrease )  any variable  by 5 percentage  , how it will affect on  y variable?i think  first  we should change  given variable(increase or decrease by 5 percentage ) first and then  sketch regression , estimate coefficients of corresponding variable and  this will answer, how effect it will be right?and if question is  how much percentage of changing we will have, then what we should do? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you are right-Betas are noting but the amount of change in Y, if a unit of independent variable changes.( Keeping other X constant)

http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpreting-regression-coefficients/

Can't you take % change in Y value when you make % change in X values. I think this will help. Example- if Y changes from 20 to 25 , you can say it has increased by 25%.

Comment: first of  all, we should know  what does it mean  percentage change of  x variable right?compare to what, i mean for example if x  variable is increase  by 5 percentage compare to  average  variable,then it is meaningful right